# Drawback of using multiple bind flags

Tags: performance, directx11, slimdx, assets

As far as I understand Direct3D 11 I have to specify certain [BindFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to use a resource in a specific stage of the pipeline.

From my experience some combinations are more common like `BindFlags.RenderTarget | BindFlags.ShaderResource` for post processing effects. And I guess it could also be quite handy sometimes to set the ShaderResource flag for DepthStencilBuffers.

So I would like to know what is happening behind the scenes. What is the drawback of simply setting all of them? Would it be a minor performance hit? Or is as bad as an individual copy of the resource for every different flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, most likely it will be performance hit (or memory usage increase). Set only those flags which you need.

Comment: not quite satisfying, but I will do that. Thanks!